# Is it possible to implement a own IASKSettingsReader?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, settings, inappsettingskit

I use core-data for saving a dynamic (small) amount of entities. These entities have a property for "Display" and "Push", which i sync with my server for each entity.

Now i want to add InApp-Settings to give the user the possibility, to change these two settings within the core data entity.

Because the behaviour and look should be like the Settings.app, i want to use the InAppSettingsKit-Project for this case.

As i read, this library allows to implement a custom SettingsStore to save the values within core data, but i need to read the entities and settings from core data too. In my opinion, it is not possible to define a own subclassed IASKSettingsReader for use.

The next problem is, that i want to use the plist on top-level to show the main-settings and then my own-store on a sub-level of the settings.

Example:

```
-> Display Settings (From plist)
--> List of entities with my own reader and store to show toggles
-> Push Settings (From plist)
--> List of entities with my own reader and store to show toggles 
-> Version (From plist)
-> About (From plist)
```

Is it possible to accomplish this goal without writing the whole settings from scratch (Which would be very painful and unflexible)?

Thanks for heading me to the right direction in advance!

**------EDIT------**

I think a possible solution would be, to save a custom plist in the needed format for InAppSettingsKit on app-start, read them in the sub-menu as source for this childpane, save the settings with a custom SettingsStore into the plist and save the data back to core data in the synchronize method.

What do you think about this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the approach that i described in the edit of the question.

The whole approach works this way:

1. Updating the data in core data with content from my server
2. Generate two plist files in InAppSettingsKit-like plist-Files within the InAppSettings.bundle
3. Implemented a SettingsStoreCoreData SettingsStore. It builds a dictionary with values from core data on init and saves them back to core-data when synchronize is called.

As Ortwin Gentz mentioned, it is possible to write a own IASKSettingsReader. But i think my approach needs less work and i have not to deal with different source types within IASKSettingsKit.

Comment: As an addition to my solution: You cannot write a file within the InAppSettings.bundle on a real device. So i have written a custom Settings Reader that searches plist files within InAppSettings.bundle, Settings.bundle and the applications documents directory, where i generate the property files. But sadly, it is not possible to set the own settingsreader as reader on the viewcontroller, because it will be overwritten when you open a subview of the settings screen.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you described sounds reasonable. You'll have to tweak the logic to set the path for the plist, though (`-locateSettingsFile:`). It should also be possible to write a replacement for `IASKSettingsReader` to dynamically set the field definitions. Alternatively, you could modify the `IASKSettingsReader.dataSource` property directly (untested, just an idea).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have implemented my approach and it works perfect.